# sed: print delimited block of lines if it matches a pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'd like to use sed to match blocks of lines delimited by *pattern1/pattern2*, and then perform operations (e.g. print the block) only on blocks which contain *pattern3*.

In the example below, I'm looking for "*catch me if you can*", inside all blocks delimited by lines matching *{* and *}* (and then I want to print the matching blocks in their entirety).

What I've tried:

```
sed -n -e '/{/,/}/{1h;1!{$!{H;d};H;x;/catch me if you can/p}}'
```

(The idea is to match blocks delimited by *{* and *}*, then accumulate each block into the hold space; at the end of each block, exchange the hold space and perform matching for "*catch me if you can*").
This doesn't work, because all matched blocks together are treated as a single block by sed, instead of each block being treated individually.

**Input data**:

```
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block2": {
    "bbb": "24680",
    "bar": "blah",
    "foo": "argh",
    "ccc": "135"
},
"block3": {
    "ddd": "zzz"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
```

**Desired output**:

```
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can"
},
```

*Note 1:* The order of the fields inside each block is random. The number of fields and the length of the values are not constant across blocks. The field I'm looking for may be missing in some blocks (as opposed to just having a different value).

*Note 2:* For educational purposes, **I'd prefer the solution to use sed**, but if that's not possible, awk or bash are fine as well. Please no perl or other tools.

**References:**

1. [Sed command summary](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/appa_03.htm)
2. [Sed one liners](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-two/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I'd do it.  There are two versions here, one for BSD (Mac OS X) `sed` (also applicable to other systems not running GNU `sed`), and one for GNU `sed`.

#### BSD `sed`

```
$ cat script.bsd-sed
/{/,/}/{
    /{/{ h; b next
    }
    /}/{ H; x; /catch me if you can/p; b next
    }
    H
    :next
}
$ sed -n -f script.bsd-sed data
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
$
```

The logic is:

- Don't print anything unless told to do so (`-n`).
- Between lines containing `{` and `}`
- If the line matches `{`, copy the pattern over the hold space and jump to label `next`.
- If the line matches `}`, add it to the hold space; switch the pattern and hold space; if the pattern space (previously hold space) matches your other pattern ('catch me if you can'), print it; jump to label `next`.
- Add the line to the hold space.

BSD (classic) `sed` requires nothing on the line after `b next`, so the `}` for the actions are on the next line.

#### GNU `sed`

```
$ cat script.gnu-sed 
/{/,/}/{
    /{/{ h; b next }
    /}/{ H; x; /catch me if you can/p; b next }
    H
    :next
}
$ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -n -f script.gnu-sed data
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
$
```

GNU `sed` recognizes semicolons or close braces after the label as terminating the command, so it allows more compact notation.  You could even flatten it all into a single line — you have to add a few semicolons:

```
$ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -n -e '/{/,/}/{ /{/{ h; b next }; /}/{ H; x; /catch me if you can/p; b next }; H; :next }' data
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
$
```

You can remove the spaces not in the pattern match too:

```
$ /opt/gnu/bin/sed -n -e '/{/,/}/{/{/{ h;b next};/}/{H;x;/catch me if you can/p;b next};H;:next}' data
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
$
```

#### Extended data file `data`

```
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block2": {
    "bbb": "24680",
    "bar": "blah",
    "foo": "argh",
    "ccc": "135"
},
"block3": {
    "ddd": "zzz"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
"block5": [
    "oops": "catch me if you can"
],
"block6": {
    "rhubarb": "dandelion"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Using sed

```
$ sed -n '/^"/{x;/catch/p;d}; ${H;x;/catch/p;d}; H' file
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
```

#### How it works

- `-n`

  This option tells sed not to print anything unless we ask
- `/^"/{x;/catch/p;d}`

  For any line that begins with a quote, this (1) exchanges the pattern and hold space, (2) checks to see if what is now in the pattern space has `catch` in it and, if so, prints it, and (3) deletes the pattern space and sed starts over working on the next line.
- `${H;x;/catch/p;d}`

  When we reach the last line, we do something similar.  We add the last line to the hold space, swap the hold space into the pattern space, check to see if it contains `catch` and, if so, prints it.  Then the pattern space is deleted.
- `H`

  For any other case,  the line is appended to the hold space.

#### Using awk

```
$ awk '/catch/{print $0 "},"}' RS='}' file
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
,
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
},
```

#### Improvements

Jonathan Leffler adds the possibility of  square bracket blocks in addition to curly brace blocks as shown in his test file `data`.  In that case for sed, try:

```
$ sed -n '/^"/{x;/{.*catch/p;d}; ${H;x;/{.*catch/p;d}; H' data
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
```

And for awk:

```
$ awk '{s=(s?s"\n":"") $0} /{/{f=1} f && /catch/{f=2} /^[]}]/{if (f==2) print s; f=0; s=""} ' data
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
```

Comment: Observation: if the file contains lines `"block5": [`, `"oops": "catch me if you can"` and `]`, those lines will be printed.  Superficially, that's fixable by using the correct search term to start the match (`/{/` instead of `/^"/`), but experimentation showed that 'block5' was still printed with the alternative search.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler OK.  Interesting.  I didn't know square-brackets were a thing.  I have updated the answer with changes that appear to handle them.

Comment: The data file looks like JSON (though I'm not sure about the trailing comma in 'block4').  JSON can have arrays with `[` and `]` as well as objects with `{` and `}`, and the question was couched in terms of `{}`.  The revision seems to work.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks.  I just revised the code to eliminate the multi-character `RS` and the spurious `,`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You are correct, it is JSON data. The example is a snippet only (and the trailing comma is meant to illustrate that the input doesn't have to be syntactically correct/complete).

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers as solutions, as they both work for my actual data set. I picked the answer from @JonathanLeffler for a more detailed theoretical analysis and for sticking with the stated block delimiters without introducing additional requirements.

Comment: That's actually pretty funny since John1024 only introduced different block delimiters to his answer in response to @JonathanLeffler introducing that additional requirement in a comment :-).

Comment: The original answer (submitted before Jonathan's post) also required that the first line of a block starts with a quote.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, **that is all**. All of its constructs to do more than s, g, and p (with -n) literally became obsolete over 40 years ago when awk was invented.

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='},?\n' -v ORS= '/catch me if you can/{print $0 RT}' file
"block1": {
    "foo": "abcd",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
    "aaa": "12345"
},
"block4": {
    "foo": "xyz",
    "bar": "catch me if you can",
}
```

Comment: With respect, that's a simplistic view of sed. You could argue in a similar fashion that awk has been obsoleted by perl. Yet, both statements are irrelevant, as both sed and awk have been maintained and repeatedly improved over the years - and are very much alive today. This becomes very important in limited embedded environments, where you have to work with a reduced set of tools (the contents of which you may not get to pick).

Comment: Having been a daily sed user for about 35 years, awk for 25, I feel I have a pretty good grasp of the way to view both tools. I make that point repeatedly and forcefully, though, to push people to think about what they are doing trying to use an arcane jumble of single letters and punctuation marks in a sed script to create a cryptic, inefficient, non-portable mess when they could write a simple, efficient, portable awk script to do the job. Like sed and unlike perl, awk is available on every standard UNIX installation and so it should be your goto tool for anything other than `s/old/new`.

Comment: wrt embedded environments with reduced toolsets - that's a very poor argument for choosing to unnecessarily use sed instead of awk since, as you point out, you have a reduced set of tools you have no control over and so you may not have sed and so that argument devolves to solving all your problems in assembly code (which, btw, isn't much less readable/maintainable than some of the sed scripts we see posted and it'd be much more efficient!). I should mention that I have nothing against sed - I still use it almost every day as it's a great tool for simple substitutions on individual lines.

Comment: I actually develop in such an embedded environment, where sed is available but awk isn't guaranteed. :)

Comment: That being said, I do see the value of awk, and use it when it seems appropriate. The point I made was exactly wrt your generalized forcefulness against sed: in order to make that point without knowing what my exact situation is, you must make assumptions to fill in the blanks - and since you don't have any data points, you have to base the assumptions on your internal (generic) view of the world. That's why I said it's a simplified approach. Regardless of experience, trying to fit every situation in a single box ("don't use sed" in this case) is bound to be wrong at least sometimes.